# HTML5 desktop application

Tags: tidesdk

We have a desktop app with python and GTK, some parts of it are developed in C, may be its for performance or legacy I am not too sure, also it has a embedded mySQL database. Now the same APP is targeted to run on Android platforms too.

Its not very feasible to rewrite the whole app. I came across this this Tide SDK where you can have GUI in HTML5. Can apps developed with Tide SDK run on android ? If yes how responsive is the UI.

Any other frameworks that I can look at for HTML5 UI, supporting both Android and Desktop.

P.S. I am not a android developer and don't know much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re: Can apps developed with Tide SDK run on android ?

nope.

You could look at doing desktop tide & mobile titanium or phonegap, and share fair bit of your app logic.